# Sitecore Show Time in 24 Hours Format in the Content Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

In an Item there is a field type "DateTime". For this field in the content editor the options to enter time is in 12 Hours Format (AM,PM). As shown below:

[image]

**How Can I show the time in 24 Hours format to the content editor.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default time format by extending `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.DateTime` class, finding the `TimePicker` inside that control and changing the `Format` property (which is set to `t` by default, which means that standard locale of Content Editor User will be used). Just to be completely honest, I don't think that changing this should be recommended for any Sitecore solution, but it's doable if required.

First of all, create your custom class inheriting from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.DateTime`, e.g.:

```cs
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace.ContentEditor
{
    public class CustomDateTime : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.DateTime
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            TimePicker timePicker = FindTimePicker(this);
            if (timePicker != null)
            {
                timePicker.Format = "HH:mm";
            }
        }

        private TimePicker FindTimePicker(Control control)
        {
            if (control != null)
            {
                var timePicker = control as TimePicker;

                if (timePicker != null)
                {
                    return timePicker;
                }

                foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
                {
                    if ((timePicker = FindTimePicker(childControl)) != null)
                    {
                        return timePicker;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in `web.config` find `<controlSources>` tag, and add following line inside that tag:

```xml
  <source mode="on" namespace="My.Assembly.Namespace.ContentEditor" assembly="My.Assembly" prefix="customcontent"/>
```

Now go to **Sitecore Desktop**, switch to **core** database, find `/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types/Datetime` item and change value of the `Control` field to `customcontent:CustomDateTime`:

[image: sitecore - date time picker - custom format]

Switch back to **master** database and check any Date Time field, e.g.:

[image: sitecore - date time picker - custom format]

Answer (score 0):

@Marek Musielak Answer is great but as he wrote that its really not recommended to change the default settings of Sitecore Solution.

So I searched a little bit more and found another way, on per-user basis. In Sitecore shell **xx/sitecore/shell** A user can also change it by going to Control Panel > Preferences > Set Your Regional and Language Options.

Comment: You can also override `DefaultRegionalIsoCode` from web.config and set that to the correct/another timezone, e.g. `da-DK`, and it will use those regional settings for all users who have not set the regional settings in their profile manually.